# SharePoint 2010 mass "Recrawl this item in the crawl log"

Tags: search, error, crawl

Is there a way that I can perform a MASS "recrawl this item in the index" in SharePoint 2010?

I have about a million documents that were successfully crawled but about 4000+ of these had "object not found" error. I checked, and some are false positives (I can search) but some are actually errors (cannot search).

Going through each one and clicking the drop down, then "recrawl this item in the index" is certainly going to be difficult. Therefore, I am looking for a way to make the job easier.

Thank you!

Comment: Incremental crawl is not working?

Comment: It's working but for some reason, throwing error on some documents (not all)). and since we have about a million, even if it's just around 1%, it's still thousands of files.